Sharepoint CAML Query for list items is returning ALL items
I am working on a UiPath automation that needs to update items in a SharePoint list. I have a SharePoint list CAML query (below) that appears to be ignoring the Where clause. We are using online SharePoint (company.sharepoint.com). I have verified the following are correct:

Checked internal names are correct
Verified all Choice/Lookup values
Checked Case Sensitivity
Checked for leading/trailing spaces

I am unable to determine why the Where seems to be ignored.
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Division'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Division1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Market'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Market1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Payer'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Payer1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Unit_x0023_s'/><Value Type='Text'>1, 2, 3</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='IPlans'/><Value Type='Text'>10, 11, 12</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='ContractEffectiveDate'/><Value Type='Date' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>4/1/2024</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Requester'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Smith John</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Lookup'>In Progress</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>

I was expecting a single list item to be returned, but continue to receive all 3 items in the list. I have tried all suggestions in the list of questions that might be a duplicate with no resolution.
Using <View><Query><Where>, I get all items returned.
Using <Query><Where>, I get the error "Value does not fall within the expected range".
Using <Where>, I get all items returned.
Using <View><Where>, I get all items returned.
I don't know what else to try.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have made this question as specific as possible with all pertinent detail.

Turns out my issue was the use of Date Time fields in my list. As I was not wanting the time portion, it caused problems when trying to find the list item. I changed the field to Text and it is now working as expected.

Turns out my issue was the use of Date Time fields in my list. As I was not wanting the time portion, it caused problems when trying to find the list item. I changed the field to Text and it is now working as expected.
